# Turbolinks implementation of document.ready with toggle on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, turbolinks

As Rails 6.1 deprecated .ready(), I tried finding an alternative that behaves similarly.
That's why thought of migrating this function over to turbolinks to get it working with Rails 6.1.
The current function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.toggle').on('click', (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + e.target.getAttribute('aria-controls')).toggleClass('is-hidden');
    })
})
```

This is the code with the 'is-hidden' that I want to toggle with the function.

```
<div class="content">
    <%= form_for :user, url: users_edit_url(@user), action: :update, method: :post, html: {id: 'user-about', class: 'is-hidden'} do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :about, autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'form', class: 'input'%>
        </div>
        <a class="toggle button is-light" aria-controls="user-about">Cancel</a>
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "button is-danger"%>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

My attempt with just blatantly switching to the turbolinks function header didn't work as planned.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    $('.toggle').on('click', (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + e.target.getAttribute('aria-controls')).toggleClass('is-hidden');
    })
});
```

Any help on how to migrate this function over to work with Rails 6.1 is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `defer: true` added in your *app/views/layouts/application.html.erb* ?

This allows to wait for the DOM to be fully loaded before running the Javascript.

```
<head>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
</head>
```